# Google pay country specific payment methods

Tags: google-pay

I have developed an app and i want to add in app payments into it. So far i have seen how the Gpay button works and i even have manged to have it working.

However google also supports localized payment methods like in India and Japan and other countries. In this link https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2651410?co=GENIE.CountryCode%3DUnited+States&hl=en

there are various methods supported per country.

Does aevery app with IAP enabled have access to all the listed payment methods as listed in the article above?.

Comment: the link that you have provided refers to Google Play and not Google Pay. Is there a chance that you've added the wrong tag?

Comment: can you ansswer my questions for google pay : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58327500/where-is-google-pay-developer-account-and-how-to-generate-public-key-to-upload-i